# split string with quote and space into array

Tags: linux, bash

I don't know how to slit string containing space 'but not those between quote' into array:

```
llusca@debian:~$ my_string='key1="value1" key2="va:lu:e2" key3="value with spaces"'
llusca@debian:~$ IFS='"\ ' arr=($my_string)
llusca@debian:~$ for i in ${arr[@]}; do echo $i; done
key1=
value1
key2=
va:lu:e2
key3=
value
with
spaces
```

expected:

```
key1="value1"
key2="va:lu:e2"
key3="value with spaces"
```

How can I do ?
Shall I use awk or other regex (the number of key/value is not fixed) ?

Comment: You write "associative array", but your expected output isn't what you'd get from an associative array, but a normal array. Which is it?

Comment: What's the origin of `my_string`, do you control that?

Comment: Can quoted strings contain escaped quotes?

Comment: Doesn't `IFS='"\ '` indicate you want to use `"` as a field sep? Good luck.

Comment: Benjamin W : array in a first time. Associative would be better- but in second time -  I don't control my_string. Ideally final result is array ([key1]="value1"...[key3]="value with space and other char except quote") - I found the beginning of solution there  https://www.tutorialkart.com/bash-shell-scripting/bash-split-string/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't have escaped double quotes inside double quotes, this can be done with bash regex :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

my_string='key1="value1" key2="va:lu:e2" key3="value with spaces"'
pattern='([^=]+)="([^"]+)" *'

declare -A result # associative array
while [[ $my_string =~ $pattern ]]; do
    result[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    my_string=${my_string:${#BASH_REMATCH[0]}} # update my_string
done

declare -p result
```